# Как в bash узнать имя последнего файла скопированного в папку?

Tags: shell, bash, linux

Пробовал варианты:

```
ls -lrt | awk '{ f=$NF }; END{ print f }'
```

и

```
ls -t1 | head -n1
```

Но последний скопированный в папку файл не показывается. Какие еще есть варианты?

UPD: Вариант тоже не работает:

```
ls -t1 | tail -n1
```

Все эти команды выдают всегда какое-то одно имя файла для моей папки. Хотя файлы продолжают непрерывно поступать в папку. Нужен именно последний попавший в папку файл. Это необязательно должен быть самый новый файл.

Comment: Если бы ещё понять, что же вы спрашиваете. Вы копируете группу файлов в папку и хотите отследить процесс? Или что? И далее. Если это то, о чём я думаю, то общего решения я не знаю, а для подсказки более частного -- нужна дополнительная информация о проблеме. (Кстати для конкретного файла -- `tail -f`)

Comment: Смотреть - не смотрел, но на stackoverflow рекомендуют dnotify, а apt-cache выдал ответ fam. Посмотрите его

    apt-cache search dnotify
    fam - наблюдение за файлами

Comment: можно по хистори грепнуть. а лучше лс и по времени создания

Comment: по времени модификации тогда уж.

Comment: А как узнать время создания?

Comment: время создания обычно узнать нельзя, есть время смены атрибутов (ctime) с помощью chmod/chown, если этих команд не было, оно совпадает со временем создания.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[@abg](/users/8847/abg), время модификации файла измеряется в *секундах*. Поэтому при массовом копировании таких файлов (с одинаковым временем) будет много.

Ваша команда

```
ls -t1 | tail -n1
```

показывает последний (самый старый, а не свежий) файл. А вот

```
ls -t | head -1
```

покажет самый новый (один из них).

А вообще-то, если опишите задачу поподробнее, то может быть найдется какое-то лучшее решение.

Answer (score 2):

Для общего случая, возможно, подойдет

```
cp -v 'from' 'to' | tail -1
```

Чтобы выделить название файла, наверное, придется воспользоваться регуляркой. 
Примерно так:

```
cp -v 'from' 'to' | tail -1 | sed 's/.*\/\(.*\)»$/\1/'
```

Comment: Что за ерунда?

    avp@avp-ubu1:~/hashcode$ cp -v | tail -1
    cp: missing file operand
    Try `cp --help' for more information.
    avp@avp-ubu1:~/hashcode$ 

@goozler, сами-то пробовали?

Comment: Я написал шаблон. Понятное дело, что команде копирования нужны входные данные: что копировать и куда. Сейчас поправлю ответ, если не понятно.

Comment: ээ, ну нут же только начало команды, имеется в виду копирование командой

    cp -v src/* dst

или что-то похожее

Comment: Это другое дело (просто не надо так небрежно делать ответы). Только, мне кажется, автор имел в виду другую задачу. 

IMHO он мониторит  каталог, а поставщики файлов (те кто копирует в каталог) ему неизвестны (либо их код недоступен).